# How can I use a part of byte[] without arraycopy?

Tags: java, byte

I wonder how to use a part of byte[] without arraycopy?

**In C Language**

```
char buf[100];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
    proc(buf + i);
}
```

But **In Java**,

```
byte[] buf = new byte[100];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
    proc(buf + i);
}
```

is not worked.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[100];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
    byte[] temp = new byte[10];
    System.arraycopy(buf, i, temp, 0, 10);
    proc(temp);
}
```

is only worked.

But, I don't like arraycopy.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm confused...do you want `proc()` to be modifying the `buf` array or not?  In your C code, it would be possible, but not in the Java code.

Comment: What is `proc()` doing? Please include that so we can suggest a solution. Without knowing how `proc` is going to use the data it is difficult to understand what you're trying to do, and therefore actually what your question is.

Comment: How are you adding an int to a char array?

Answer (score 8):

You could always extend your "proc" function to take 3 parameters like so:

```
proc(byte[] a, int offset, int length)
```

That's the best way to mimic C-array functionality in Java.

Comment: Seconded. This is a very idiomatic approach that is used in many places in the standard library.

Comment: "proc" function modifies "buf" argument like doing sort or something. (what proc doing is not matter.) I just want modify argument without arraycopy or index.

Comment: This is a deceptively easy question but very relevant if you are coming from a C background. Basically, you have to unlearn all your pointer thinking. There is no equivalent concept in Java. What brandx proposed above is pretty much the standard pattern for dealing with primitive arrays.

Comment: @pap: *was* the standard way of handling arrays of course, I've added a ByteBuffer example that does the same thing

Answer (score 3):

The class `java.util.Arrays` has some useful methods like:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[100];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
    proc(Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, i, buf.length));
}
```

more: [copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a index parameter to your `proc`

```
void proc(byte[] array, int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < array.length; ++i)
    {
        // do something   
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code instead of arraycopy

```
byte[] buf = new byte[100];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
            byte[] temp = new byte[10];
                  temp[i%10] = buf[i];



        }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers included ByteBuffer, I'll show another way:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ProcByteBuffer {

    private static final int BUF_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int BIG_BUF_SIZE = 10 * BUF_SIZE;

    public static void proc(final ByteBuffer buf) {

        // for demo purposes
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            System.out.printf("%02X", Integer.valueOf(buf.get() & 0xFF));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ByteBuffer bigBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(BIG_BUF_SIZE);

        // for demo purposes
        for (int i = 0; i < BIG_BUF_SIZE; i++) {
            bigBuf.put((byte) i);
        }
        bigBuf.position(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < BIG_BUF_SIZE; i += BUF_SIZE) {
            bigBuf.position(i);
            bigBuf.limit(i + BUF_SIZE);
            proc(bigBuf.slice());
        }
    }
}
```

Any changes to the slice (the buf argument to proc()) will be visible to the underlying array.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an array is just a pointer to somewhere in memory, and buf+i has meaning (it means a place in memory i bytes on - which is also an array)

In java an Array is an object with length and code attached. There is no way to have a reference to an "array inside an array", and the "+" operator has no meaning.

Comment: Hmm. Then there is no way to do like C does. Only arraycopy or passes index argument with buf. thx for your answer.